# How to fetch the content of iframe in a php variable?

Tags: php, javascript, html

My code is somewhat like this:

```
<?php

if($_REQUEST['post'])
{
    $title=$_REQUEST['title'];
    $body=$_REQUEST['body'];
    echo $title.$body;
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="texteditor.js">
</script>

<form action="" method="post">
       Title: <input type="text" name="title"/><br>

       <a id="bold" class="font-bold"> B </a> 
       <a id="italic" class="italic"> I </a>

       Post: <iframe id="textEditor" name="body"></iframe>

       <input type="submit" name="post" value="Post" />
</form>
```

The texteditor.js file code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
document.getElementById('textEditor').contentWindow.document.designMode="on";
document.getElementById('textEditor').contentWindow.document.close();
$("#bold").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("selected")){
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
    }
    else{
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    }
    boldIt();
});

$("#italic").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("selected")){
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
    }
    else{
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    }
    ItalicIt();
});


});

function boldIt(){
    var edit = document.getElementById("textEditor").contentWindow;
    edit.focus();
    edit.document.execCommand("bold", false, "");
    edit.focus();
}

function ItalicIt(){  
    var edit = document.getElementById("textEditor").contentWindow;
    edit.focus();
    edit.document.execCommand("italic", false, "");
    edit.focus();
}

function post(){
    var iframe = document.getElementById("body").contentWindow;
}
```

Actually I want to fetch data from this `text editor` (which is created using `iframe` and `javascript`) and store it in some other place. I'm not able to fetch the content that is entered in the editor (i.e. iframe).

Please help me out in this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the content of iframe in a php variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074367/how-to-get-the-content-of-iframe-in-a-php-variable)

Comment: that question was closed. since i'm new to this. i don't know how to reopen after editing the question. so, i posted a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that because it is not allowed.

Javascript is not allowed access to other frames/iframes, as it would result in a security breach.

Try to implement your editor inline in a `<div></div>` instead of `iframe`

Comment: i tried <div> instead of <iframe> but the editor is not working now... do i require to make some changes in javascript file also??

Comment: You have to *implement* your editor in your page directly. Simply linking it in won't help you much.

Comment: then how would i store the content that will be edited? i need to store it.

Comment: @Story Teller: sorry but i couldn't get you. what are you trying to ask me?

Comment: can you quote some code sample in Html5 by which i can get how to do what i want...??